# Preloading HTML Files from the app Bundle Before being Displayed in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiwebview

I have an application that I'm currently working on for the iPhone that will support iOS 5.0 and above. The app is essentially an information based app that makes use of sliding view controllers similar to Path & Facebook. Table views that push a new view onto the stack. I have chosen to display some content in a UIWebView that loads a number of HTML files locally from the bundle, mainly because the information is static and it allows me to style if extremely easily.

Nothing fancy about how I'm doing it. The sending view controller passes the name of the necessary HTML file through depending on the indexPath.row that was selected in the table view. Webview is populated in the viewDidLoad method as such:

```
[_detailsWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: _htmlFile ofType:@"html"] isDirectory:NO]]];
```

The app supports iOS 5 and above which means Im looking at iPod touch 3rd and 4th gen, iPhone 3GS, iPhone 4 and 4S and iPhone 5 and the new iPod touch. On the iPhone 5 the UIWebView loads the local HTML file rather snappy as you would expect, but there is a delay in populating it on older devices.

Is there a way to preload the HTML files before getting to the viewDidLoad method of the displaying ViewController?

Answer (score 0):

Make a method where u want to preload HTML files ie ViewController

```
-(void)loadHTMLFiles:(NSString*)htmlFile
{
    //I assume u have set IBOutlet of detailsWebView 
   [_detailsWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:htmlFile ofType:@"html"] isDirectory:NO]]];
}
```

Now after pushing your newView ie ViewController:

```
 [ViewController *objViewController = [ViewController alloc]init];
 //here newView is pushed in navigation or add SubView
[objViewController loadHTMLFiles:yourHTMLFileName];
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect if you just read the files into a NSData object, then free the object, that will help greatly. The idea is to get the files loaded into the file system cache, so they are already there when the web view wants to read them. Try that first as its the easiest thing to do.